# Sync S3 Bucket and listen for changes

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I've got an AWS S3 bucket, where I place on a weekly basis a new ZIP file.

I want to add a functionality to my existing Web Service, written with Spring Boot: synchronize the bucket locally and watch for changes.

For the time being, synchronization works well: whenever a new file is added to the bucket, it gets downloaded locally. However, I don't know to listen for file updates, this is, a method that fires when a new file is downloaded locally. Can it be done?

This is the piece of code I've:

```
#  --------
# | AWS S3 |
#  --------
s3.credentials-access-key=***
s3.credentials-secret-key=****
s3.bucket = my-bucket
s3.remote-dir = zips
s3.local-dir = D:/s3-bucket/
```

```java
@Log4j2
@Configuration
public class S3Config {

    public static final String OUT_CHANNEL_NAME = "s3filesChannel";

    @Value("${s3.credentials-access-key}") private String accessKey;
    @Value("${s3.credentials-secret-key}") private String secretKey;
    @Value("${s3.remote-dir}") private String remoteDir;
    @Value("${s3.bucket}") private String s3bucket;
    @Value("${s3.local-dir}") private String localDir;

    /*
     * AWS S3
     */
    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 getAmazonS3(

    ){
        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
                .build();
        return s3client;        
    }

    @Bean
    public S3SessionFactory s3SessionFactory(AmazonS3 pAmazonS3) {
        return new S3SessionFactory(pAmazonS3);
    }

    @Bean
    public S3InboundFileSynchronizer s3InboundFileSynchronizer(S3SessionFactory pS3SessionFactory) {
        S3InboundFileSynchronizer sync = new S3InboundFileSynchronizer(pS3SessionFactory);
        sync.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
        sync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        String fullRemotePath = s3bucket.concat("/").concat(remoteDir);
        sync.setRemoteDirectory(fullRemotePath);
        sync.setFilter(new S3RegexPatternFileListFilter(".*\\.zip$"));
        return sync;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = OUT_CHANNEL_NAME, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "30"))
    public S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
        S3InboundFileSynchronizer pS3InboundFileSynchronizer
    ) {
        S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource = new S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(pS3InboundFileSynchronizer);
        messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File(localDir));
        messageSource.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean("s3filesChannel")
    public PollableChannel s3FilesChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow(
            S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource pS3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource,
            GtfsBizkaibus pGtfsBizkaibus,
            @Qualifier("fileProcessor") MessageHandler pMessageHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(pS3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource, e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .handle(pMessageHandler)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean("fileProcessor")
    public MessageHandler fileProcessor() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(localDir));
        handler.setExpectReply(false); // end of pipeline, reply not needed
        handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND);
        handler.setNewFileCallback((file, msg) -> {
            log.debug("New file created... " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        });
        return handler;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` does all the necessary work for you: when new file is added into a remote bucket, it is downloaded to local dir and produced as a `payload` in the message to be sent to the configured channel.

When remote file is modified, it is also downloaded to local dir.

Starting with version `5.0`, the `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` provides this option:

```
/**
 * Switch the local {@link FileReadingMessageSource} to use its internal
 * {@code FileReadingMessageSource.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner}.
 * @param useWatchService the {@code boolean} flag to switch to
 * {@code FileReadingMessageSource.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner} on {@code true}.
 * @since 5.0
 */
public void setUseWatchService(boolean useWatchService) {
    this.fileSource.setUseWatchService(useWatchService);
    if (useWatchService) {
        this.fileSource.setWatchEvents(
                FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE,
                FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.MODIFY,
                FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.DELETE);
    }
}
```

If that makes some sense to you.

But yeah... with S3 to SQS notification it is also going to be a good solution. There is an `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` in Spring Integration AWS project.

Comment: So I can add `messageSource.setUseWatchService(true);`, but what else should I do? Defining a new Bean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You have that `OUT_CHANNEL_NAME` as an output from your `S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource`, so you need a `@ServiceActivator` to consume messages from this channel. Those messages are going to contain `File` payload for local copy from S3 bucket. You don't need any `FileWritingMessageHandler` because remote files are already located in the local dir after syncing  from S3.

Comment: I've got the solution. I'm posting it. Thanks @Artem Bilan

Answer (score 5):

You can use S3 Event Notifications and an SQS queue.  Basically when an object is added to your bucket, S3 can publish an event to a registered SQS queue.  You can then have your on-premise application long poll the queue for new events and process any events that are added.

See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, as @Artem Bilian suggested, I've make use of `@ServiceActivator` annotation. Here it's the full example:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.S3InboundFileSynchronizer;
import org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.aws.support.S3SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.aws.support.filters.S3RegexPatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.file.support.FileExistsMode;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.PollableChannel;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
@Configuration
public class S3Config {

    public static final String IN_CHANNEL_NAME = "s3filesChannel";

    @Value("${s3.credentials-access-key}") private String accessKey;
    @Value("${s3.credentials-secret-key}") private String secretKey;
    @Value("${s3.remote-dir}") private String remoteDir;
    @Value("${s3.bucket}") private String s3bucket;
    @Value("${s3.local-dir}") private String localDir;

    /*
     * AWS S3
     */
    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 getAmazonS3(

    ){
        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
                .build();
        return s3client;        
    }

    @Bean
    public S3SessionFactory s3SessionFactory(AmazonS3 pAmazonS3) {
        return new S3SessionFactory(pAmazonS3);
    }

    @Bean
    public S3InboundFileSynchronizer s3InboundFileSynchronizer(S3SessionFactory pS3SessionFactory) {
        S3InboundFileSynchronizer sync = new S3InboundFileSynchronizer(pS3SessionFactory);
        sync.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
        sync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        String fullRemotePath = s3bucket.concat("/").concat(remoteDir);
        sync.setRemoteDirectory(fullRemotePath);
        sync.setFilter(new S3RegexPatternFileListFilter(".*\\.zip$"));
        return sync;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = IN_CHANNEL_NAME, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "30"))
    public S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
        S3InboundFileSynchronizer pS3InboundFileSynchronizer
    ) {
        S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource = new S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(pS3InboundFileSynchronizer);
        messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File(localDir));
        messageSource.setUseWatchService(true);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean("s3filesChannel")
    public PollableChannel s3FilesChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow(
            S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource pS3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource,
            @Qualifier("fileProcessor") MessageHandler pMessageHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(pS3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource, e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .handle(pMessageHandler)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean("fileProcessor")
    public MessageHandler fileProcessor() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(localDir));
        handler.setExpectReply(false); // end of pipeline, reply not needed
        handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
        return handler;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = IN_CHANNEL_NAME, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "30"))
    public void asada(Message<?> message) {
        // TODO
        log.debug("<< New message!");
    }

}
```

Note that I've replaced `OUT_CHANNEL_NAME` by `IN_CHANNEL_NAME`.

PS: I'm almost new to Spring Integration, so I'm still learning its concepts.